# RedirectToAction with optional parameters?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

In my action I need to redirect to below Action (I m using aspx view engine).

```
  [HttpGet]
  public virtual ActionResult Home(Guid id, int? pid)
```

and Url of this page is like:

```
http://localhost:56445/Bid/Home/23b0b096-aea8-46e4-9a7d-a2bd00eaf72e
```

In my current action I have value of Guid but not pid.

I m trying  `return RedirectToAction("Home","Bid",new {Guid=23b0b096-aea8-46e4-9a7d-a2bd00eaf72e,pid=0});`

but it is wrong: it made a url having query sting like below with the following error:

```
http://localhost:56445/Bid/Home?Guid=23b0b096-aea8-46e4-9a7d-a2bd00eaf72e&pid=0

The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Guid' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Home(System.Guid, System.Nullable`1[System.Int32])' in 'IntraClockAuction.Web.Controllers.BidController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters
```

Can you please guide and help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass parameter with same name as you have accepted in Action Method, which in your case is `id` not `Guid`

Change

```
return RedirectToAction("Home","Bid",new {Guid=23b0b096-aea8-46e4-9a7d-a2bd00eaf72e,pid=0});
```

To

```
return RedirectToAction("Home","Bid",new {id="23b0b096-aea8-46e4-9a7d-a2bd00eaf72e",pid=0});
```